# How to remotely install Java + Tomcat on a remote Linux machine from a Java webapp?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, web-applications, ssh

I have a Java web application running on a WildFly server.

What I want to achieve:

1. A user clicks a button (or does something else) in the WildFly application.
2. Java is installed on some remote machine (not the one running the application on WildFly).
3. Tomcat is installed on the remote machine.
4. .war is deployed on Tomcat on the remote machine.

Suppose I have all the necessary data to operate on the remote machine (hostname, user, password, privileges).

All that is known is that the remote machine operates on Linux (distro unknown).

How could I approach this problem? Maybe executing some ssh commands with `ProcessBuilder`? I think the biggest issue is to somehow make the Java installation general enough to work on every (or most of) Linux distros.

EDIT: [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) was tried as a candidate solution but the configuration seems too complicated. I mean, it feels like there should be an easier solution for this kind of work.

Comment: It may better to try using solutions targeted for this kind of work (configuration management)-- Puppet/Chef/rundeck ..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://salt-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/, You can use saltstack to deploy and control servers like(puppet and chef) and use HTTP(REST) API to make some actions like deploy a new app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at https://www.docker.io/ for the deployment.

Comment: I considered this. However, the website says "Please note Docker is currently under heavy development. It should not be used in production (yet)." I need a solution that works in production.

Comment: You could create a tar-ball with both Java and Tomcat and use scp to copy it to the server along with a war file. But if you need tomcat to start on reboot you have to create an init-script or service and this is not done the same way on all linux distributions. Here puppet could help.